# How can ı fix this problem about C# “must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial”

Tags: c#

Here is my database context application for using Entity Framework,

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options);
    }
```

In ApplicationDbContext gives me "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial” that error. I did get, set part in my another c# class document.

And ı got another error for Add-Migration, I installed microsoft entity tools but ıt did not recognize add-migration in command screen:

Comment: Did you copy this code from somewhere?

Comment: It's self-evident. Do what it says and define the ctor.

Comment: Please consider not rolling back edits that improve your post!

Comment: I saw this code in a video. For database entity framework connection.

Comment: Ok, Sorry for that

Comment: Constructors, like any non abstract method, needs a body, even if it's empty. So you need to add braces.

Comment: Where should braces must be? Thank You.

Comment: @RafaelVeronezi: newcomers need to learn how to a) read the language documentation, and b) learn to use various search tools available to them, including the site's own search feature and their favorite web search tool. Oh, and...you don't get to tell other people whether they should downvote or not. You aren't the boss of anyone else here.

Comment: This code is NOT what EF generates for you by default, nor is it in official documents, so this should 100% be closed, if you get this deep into EF you are expected to have some basic understanding of syntax and class structure, otherwise use the tools and templates or copy your code from the official getting started documentation

Comment: @PeterDuniho I looked at same question's replies, but it did not help me, So ı wondered that it might be helpful to ask this question with another context.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare an empty constructor:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Just to give some insight about the error message, the syntax you've used is valid if you're in an abstract class or partial class declaration. If you have an abstract class it means that you're declaring a method that must be implemented by the inherited classes, in that case you should prefix the method with the `abstract` keyword. Partial classes allows you to have your class declared among several files, so you can have the signature of a method on a file and the implementation on a different file. Finally, [extern methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern) are mostly used with DllImport and tells the C# compiler that the implementation of the method is done outside of your code.

Comment: In EF it is common to NOT declare anything extra in this constructor, as configuration is usually injected through DI or mostly in the `OnModelCreating` event handler.

Comment: That's right. Either way the constructor need to exist to supply the arguments for the base class constructor since `DbContext` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.